# Is there a need to check `IsSuccessStatusCode` after `ReadAsStringAsync`?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

consider:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("url");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return false;
var getResponsestring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// check response.IsSuccessStatusCode again ??
```

Do I now need to check `IsSuccessStatusCode` again ? or is exception handling covers all errors ?

That is can `IsSuccessStatusCode` be `true` after `GetAsync` but `false` after `ReadAsStringAsync` ?

Comment: i don't get the point of the question. the status code of your response _won't change_. so `isSuccessStatusCode` won't change, either. (and don't forget: you _can_ get an error code _with_ an accompanying body)

Comment: `IsSuccessStatusCode` checks only that response status code is in the range 200-299. Even with 200 response code you can get an error while trying to read a content.

Comment: so if I understand correctly @FranzGleichmann you say no need to check again and @ Fabio you say yes need to check again ?

Comment: @kofifus this depends on the design of your client and server applications. `isSuccessStatusCode` just checks if status code is in 2XX range. However you might want specific behaviour for other status codes. It's a convenience method for SOME client applications. Whether it will work for you will depend on the design of your application.

Comment: @zaitsman my question is if  the result of isSuccessStatusCode can change between before ReadAsStringAsync and after it

Comment: No, you only have to check `IsSuccessStatusCode` after posting/getting your request. `ReadAsStringAsync` won't change the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property.

Comment: @imsmn can you post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to check the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property after calling [`ReadAsStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_ReadAsStringAsync), once after invoking `client.GetAsync` is enough.
[`ReadAsStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_ReadAsStringAsync) won't change the value of `IsSuccessStatusCode`.

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=winrt-20348) state:

> Gets a value that indicates whether the HTTP response was successful.